# Overfull \hbox error on a blank line in LaTeX?

Tags: warnings

I'm getting really confused by this. In my code, line 39 is completely blank, there's no errors anywhere else and everything fits in the margins yet I'm still getting an `Overfull \hbox (34.204pt too wide) in paragraph` error. It has nothing to do with what's on the line, because empty or not, the error is always line 39. I've included my code below, does anyone else have this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mcode}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

% \mcodelisting{Program/Function descriptor}{Usage}{filename with extension}
\newcommand{\mcodelisting}[3]{\pagebreak
\appendix{\textbf{#1} \mcode{2-3/#3} \textbf{#2}}
\lstinputlisting{C:/Users/******/Documents/MATLAB/2-3/#3}
}


\title{2.3 Continued Fractions}         % used by \maketitle
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Rational Numbers}

\subsubsection*{Programming Task}
A program using the given algorithm to compute the partial quotients and convergents of a fraction $u/v$ is shown on page ??.


\begin{enumerate}
\item Taking $u = 112, v = 27$ gives partial quotients $a_n$ as 4,6,1,3 and convergents $p_n/q_n$ as $\frac{4}{1}, \frac{25}{6}, \frac{29}{7}, \frac{112}{27}$
\item Taking $u = 4803, v = 3395$ gives partial quotients 1,2,2,2,3,6 and 13 with convergents $\frac{1}{1}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{5}, \frac{17}{12}, \frac{58}{41}, \frac{365}{258}, \frac{4803}{3395}$
\item Taking $u = 276272, v = 72159$ gives partial quotients 3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5 and 3 with convergents $\frac{3}{1}, \frac{4}{1}, \frac{19}{5}, \frac{23}{6}, \frac{134}{35}, \frac{1229}{321},     \frac{2592}{677}, \frac{16781}{4383}, \frac{86497}{22592}, \frac{276272}{72159}$
\item Finally, if $u = 11683474147$ and $v = 863334886$ then the partial quotients are 13,1,1,7,11,1,2,5,2,3,1,1,9,1,2,12,9,5 and the convergents are $\frac{1}{1}$
\end{enumerate}


% Page break inserted by \mcodelisting
\mcodelisting{Program}{for question 1}{question1.m}

\end{document}             % End of document.
```

(Line 39 in this case is the blank line immediately before `% Page break ...`)

Comment: What I can say so far is that the problem only appears when using `\mcodelisting{Program}{for question 1}{question1.m}`. Without that line it compiles just fine. Now I'm not sure wether the problem lies in the mcode package or your `newcommand` definition but I would guess it's because of the way your `mcodelisting` is defined.

Comment: Edit: How does your m-file look like? When I use just some m-file of mine I can also compile just fine. Meaning the `newcommand` works normal and the mcode package also does its job.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that your m-file contains too long lines.